# Is the && operator in actionscript lazy?

Tags: actionscript

```
var b:Boolean = condition1() && condition2();
```

In this statement, if `condition1()` evaluates to false, will `condition2()` be evaluated?

Comment: Have you tried it out? You could put a trace() call in both condition1 and condition2, then see which gets called. Help using the trace command: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3trace/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The `&&` operator (and also `||`) is *short-circuited*.

This has been explained in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_AND.

> Returns `expression1` if it is `false` or can be converted to `false`, and `expression2` otherwise. Examples of values that can be converted to `false` are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, and `undefined`. If you use a function call as `expression2`, **the function is not called if `expression1` evaluates to `false`**.

Answer (score 3):

A little googling indicates [yes](http://flash-creations.com/notes/actionscript_operators.php). Also, the usual term is [short-circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), rather than [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

Correct. The compiler should always take the quickest path out of a conditional. If any test case fails, the compiler knows that the results of further tests are irrelevant and decides to bail right then and there.

```
var obj:Object = null;
if( obj && obj.name == "fred" )
{
    trace( "Hi, fred." );
}
```

You will never see "Hi, fred." because Obj is null. Good thing too, because the second test case will throw an error since you cannot dereference a null object in that manner. I've used this particular approach many times when I need to make sure some object is not null before dereferencing it.